# Nginx reverse proxy without port

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have project running on nginx and through nginx I am presenting this project to the UI with a domain of ssl. It broadcasts from port 443 with example.com. I publish my project, which is a different docker container, over example.com:5000 to live on SSL, but this example.com:5000 address needs to be published from example1.com, that is, it is port-free to the other docker container interface. I would like to change the .How should I fix the Nginx configuration.

Comment: https://www.antitree.com/2017/06/running-nginx-on-all-ports/